# ArcPy UpdateCursor auto pausing after every 1000 records

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor, performance, oracle-dbms

I have an update cursor running that updates a field based on a lookup table (Python dictionary).  The cursor completes fine, but seems to pause and hold after each 1000 records - I have a test in it to write out the time each 100 records, see code.  If you look at the results - you can see the first 1000 records don't seem to take any time, but then the 1100th result is delayed.  I am running this on an Oracle DB.

```
x = 0
cur = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(property_fc,["FACILITYID","GLOBALID"])
for row in cur:
    x = x + 1
    if (x % 100) == 0:
        print("At {}, {}".format(x,datetime.now() - vST))
    if row[1] in global_id_lut:
        row[0] = global_id_lut[row[1]]
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like normal AUTOCOMMIT interval behavior to me.

Answer (score 9):

By default the [auto commit](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/auto-commit.htm) interval is set to 1000. You can change the interval using the following:

```
arcpy.env.autoCommit = 5000
```

Comment: Probably ought to caveat on the law of diminishing returns with respect to increasing commit intervals.